# Criar um array separado por grupos de data

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Pessoal quero criar um array separado em grupos por data do resultado de uma consulta feita no DB

exemplo:

```
// [...]
$sql = $this->db->query($query) or die (sprintf("Falha: %s", $this->db->error()));
if ($sql->num_rows) {
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_object()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}
// [...]
```

exemplo Teste:

```
$data[] = array(
    'data' => '2015-02-05',
    'refer' => 'X741852',
    'favorecido' => 'MARIA',
    'debito' => '2.500'
);
$data[] = array(
    'data' => '2015-02-05',
    'refer' => 'B890656',
    'favorecido' => 'EDUARDA',
    'debito' => '500'
);
$data[] = array(
    'data' => '2015-02-18',
    'refer' => 'CK546045',
    'favorecido' => 'JOAO',
    'debito' => '42.050'
);
$data[] = array(
    'data' => '2014-06-09',
    'refer' => 'FE55852',
    'favorecido' => 'CHARLES',
    'debito' => '28.500'
);
$data[] = array(
    'data' => '2014-06-09',
    'refer' => 'X741852',
    'favorecido' => 'VIVIANE',
    'debito' => '74.2500'
);
```

saida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2015-02-05
            [refer] => X741852
            [favorecido] => MARIA
            [debito] => 2.500
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2015-02-05
            [refer] => B890656
            [favorecido] => EDUARDA
            [debito] => 500
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2015-02-18
            [refer] => CK546045
            [favorecido] => JOAO
            [debito] => 42.050
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2014-06-09
            [refer] => FE55852
            [favorecido] => CHARLES
            [debito] => 28.500
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2014-06-09
            [refer] => X741852
            [favorecido] => VIVIANE
            [debito] => 74.2500
        )

)
```

Resultado Pretendido:

```
Array
(
    [2015-02-05] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 2015-02-05
                    [refer] => X741852
                    [favorecido] => MARIA
                    [debito] => 2.500
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 2015-02-05
                    [refer] => B890656
                    [favorecido] => EDUARDA
                    [debito] => 500
                )
         )

    [2015-02-18] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 2015-02-18
                    [refer] => CK546045
                    [favorecido] => JOAO
                    [debito] => 42.050
                )
        )

    [2014-06-09] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 2014-06-09
                    [refer] => FE55852
                    [favorecido] => CHARLES
                    [debito] => 28.500
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 2014-06-09
                    [refer] => X741852
                    [favorecido] => VIVIANE
                    [debito] => 74.2500
                )
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente só precisa disso:

```
$out = array();
$i = 0;

foreach( $data as $item) $out[$item['data']][$i++] = $item;
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/PVtZCN)**

Aplicado ao código:

```
$sql = $this->db->query($query) or die (sprintf("Falha: %s", $this->db->error()));
$i = 0;
if ($sql->num_rows) {
  while ($row = $sql->fetch_object()) $data[$row['data']][$i++] = $row;
}
```

Se puder resetar o índice interno, fica mais simples:

```
$sql = $this->db->query($query) or die (sprintf("Falha: %s", $this->db->error()));
if ($sql->num_rows) {
  while ($row = $sql->fetch_object()) $data[$row['data']][] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Bacco, optei por sua solução por ser mais simples

Comment: @smigol notou a diferença do i++ né? No seu exemplo, os indices internos continuam 1, 2, muda de grupo 3, 4, 5, etc. Se nao precisar disso, pode remover o `$i` da jogada

Comment: sim sim, vlw cara. Agora to com outra dúvida havia pensado em criar esse grupo por data por achar ser mais simples para lista o relatório, porém não to conseguindo ;( Achar melhor criar um novo post ou tudo bem se add a este post?

Comment: @smigol como já tem duas respostas, acho melhor separado. Mas tome o cuidado de fazer ela bem específica ao problema que vc quer resolver. Em vez de perguntar em cima do que está tentando fazer, priorize demonstrar o resultado onde quer chegar. Às vezes quando você parte só do código, acaba deixando de receber idéias ótimas e cai no [Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499)

Comment: Blz @Bacco, farei isso ;)

Answer (score 1):

Atribua a data como chave do array, assim:

```
while ($row = $sql->fetch_object())
    $data[$row['data']][] = $row;
```

Caso não tenha mais de uma linha de código no laço de repetição, pode remover os brakets. (colchetes).

Comment: Obrigado Daniel, funcionou perfeitamente