# Exibir relatório separado por grupos de datas

Tags: php, array

Pessoal pretendo exibir um relatorio separando os resultados em grupos de data conforme exemplo abaixo

```
|   REF.    |   NOME    |   DEBITO  |
=====================================
|   X741852 |   MARIA   |   2.500   |
|   B890656 |   EDUARDA |   500     |
|
|   Data: 2015-02-05
-------------------------------------
|   CK54604 |   JOAO    |   42.050  |
|
|   Data: 2015-02-18
-------------------------------------
|   FE55852 |   CHARLES |   28.500  |
|   X741852 |   VIVIANE |   74.2500 |
|
|   Data: 2014-06-09
-------------------------------------
```

Os dados vem de uma consulta no DB

```
$sql = $this->db->query($query) or die (sprintf("Falha: %s", $this->db->error()));

if ($sql->num_rows) {
    $html = "<table border=\"1\">
        <tr>
            <th>REF.</th>
            <th>FAVORECIDO</th>
            <th>DEBITO</th>
        </tr>";

    while ($row = $sql->fetch_object()) {

        $html .= "<tr>
            <td>{$row->refer}</td>
            <td>{$row->favorecido}</td>
            <td>{$row->favorecido}</td>
        </tr>";

        /*
        // aqui não sei como separar, por uma linha com a DATA conforme exemplo acima
        if ($row->data) {
             $html .= "<tr>
                <td rowspan="3">Data: {$row->data}</td>
            </tr>";
        }
        */
    }

    $html .= "</table>";

    echo $html;
}
```

Meu array de teste

```
$data[] = array(
    'data' => '2015-02-05',
    'refer' => 'X741852',
    'favorecido' => 'MARIA',
    'debito' => '2.500'
);
$data[] = array(
    'data' => '2015-02-05',
    'refer' => 'B890656',
    'favorecido' => 'EDUARDA',
    'debito' => '500'
);
$data[] = array(
    'data' => '2015-02-18',
    'refer' => 'CK546045',
    'favorecido' => 'JOAO',
    'debito' => '42.050'
);
$data[] = array(
    'data' => '2014-06-09',
    'refer' => 'FE55852',
    'favorecido' => 'CHARLES',
    'debito' => '28.500'
);
$data[] = array(
    'data' => '2014-06-09',
    'refer' => 'X741852',
    'favorecido' => 'VIVIANE',
    'debito' => '74.2500'
);
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Criar um array separado por grupos de data](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108018/criar-um-array-separado-por-grupos-de-data)

Comment: @smigol explique melhor o passo em que está e a dificuldade, pq senão fica igual a outra. Ao menos explique pq a outra nao resolveu como vc esperava, e por que nao está conseguindo usar os dados para montar o relatório, etc.

Comment: To editando pessoal

Comment: @smigol veja se é isso que vc quer: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105060/ Em especial a 2a parte da minha resposta, que mostra como criar o título quando muda determinado valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue código, está bem simples, na verdade gerei um novo array baseado no array inicial `data`

```
<?php

$data[] = array(
    'data' => '2015-02-05',
    'refer' => 'X741852',
    'favorecido' => 'MARIA',
    'debito' => '2.500'
);
$data[] = array(
    'data' => '2015-02-05',
    'refer' => 'B890656',
    'favorecido' => 'EDUARDA',
    'debito' => '500'
);
$data[] = array(
    'data' => '2015-02-18',
    'refer' => 'CK546045',
    'favorecido' => 'JOAO',
    'debito' => '42.050'
);
$data[] = array(
    'data' => '2014-06-09',
    'refer' => 'FE55852',
    'favorecido' => 'CHARLES',
    'debito' => '28.500'
);
$data[] = array(
    'data' => '2014-06-09',
    'refer' => 'X741852',
    'favorecido' => 'VIVIANE',
    'debito' => '74.2500'
);

$novo_array = array();

// Looop para construir Novo array separado pela data
foreach ( $data as $value ) {
    $novo_array[ $value[ "data" ] ][ ] = $value;
}

?>

<html>
    <head><title>Apenas Teste</title></head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>REF.</th>
                <th>NOME</th>
                <th>DEBITO</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach( $novo_array as $data => $linhas ): ?>

                <?php foreach( $linhas as $linha ): ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $linha["refer"];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $linha["favorecido"];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $linha["debito"];?></td>
                    </tr>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">DATA: <?php echo $data;?></td>
                </tr>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Testei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente, caso tenha erros me comunique.

Comment: Obrigado @JhonatanSimoes, fico feliz por te compreendido meu problema

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente você precisa garantir que os dados já estão ordenados pela data.

Segundo seu array de teste, temos o seguinte array:

```
$data = array(
    0 => array(
        'data'       => '2015-02-05',
        'refer'      => 'X741852',
        'favorecido' => 'MARIA',
        'debito'     => '2.500'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'data'       => '2015-02-05',
        'refer'      => 'B890656',
        'favorecido' => 'EDUARDA',
        'debito'     => '500'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'data'       => '2015-02-18',
        'refer'      => 'CK546045',
        'favorecido' => 'JOAO',
        'debito'     => '42.050'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'data'       => '2014-06-09',
        'refer'      => 'FE55852',
        'favorecido' => 'CHARLES',
        'debito'     => '28.500'
    ),
    4 => array(
        'data'       => '2014-06-09',
        'refer'      => 'X741852',
        'favorecido' => 'VIVIANE',
        'debito'     => '74.2500'
    ),
);
```

O código para exibi-lo em uma tabela HTML é este abaixo (você pode mudar o layout de exibição caso deseja, mas o código PHP continua o mesmo):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>REF.</th>
        <th>NOME</th>
        <th>DEBITO</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php 
    foreach ($data as $index => $dados) {
        echo '<tr>';

        foreach ($dados as $key => $value) {
            echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
        }

        // Analisa quando a próxima data muda e imprime
        $dataAtual   = $dados['data'];
        $dataProximo = $data[$index+1];

        if ($dataAtual != $dataProximo) {
            echo '<td>'.$dataAtual.'</td>';
        }

        echo '</tr>';
    } 
    ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

PS: Esse formato faz o que você pediu, imprime a data **depois** dos dados, porém acho isso estranho, na minha opinião é melhor exibir a data **antes** dos dados, ficaria assim:

```
<?php 
$dataAnterior = null;

foreach ($data as $dados) {
    echo '<tr>';

    // Analisa quando a data muda e imprime
    $dataAtual = $dados['data'];
    if ($dataAnterior != $dataAtual) {
        echo '<td>'.$dataAtual.'</td>';
        $dataAnterior = $dataAtual;
    }

    foreach ($dados as $key => $value) {
        echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';
} 
?>
```

Comment: Muito bom @EdsonHoracioJunior, obrigado meu velho